# Genarate list of objects in test using spock

Tags: java, groovy, java-8, spock

I am writing a spock test, wherein I need to generate some test data (Fixtures). I know how it could be done in Java, but failing to get it implemented in spock(groovy).

I'm new to groovy, hence I'm providing my java implementation

Java implementation as follows :

```
List<Employee> employees= LongStream.range(1, 70).mapToObj(id -> {
        Employee emp = new Employee ();
        emp.setEmployeeId(id);
        return emp ;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm trying to achieve the same using groovy, but unable to get it right.

```
def employees = [1..70].each { id ->
        def emp = new Employee()
        emp.setEmployeeId(id)
        employees << emp
    }
```

Appraciate any help to fix the groovy code..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[1..70]` creates a list with one element that is a range. You want to use something like `(1..70)`:

```
(1..70).each{employees << new Employee(employeeId: it)}
```

Just a side note: you can avoid appending to the list by just creating one using `collect`:

```
List<Employee> employees = (1..70).collect{new Employee(employeeId: it)}
```